# Corrupted UV map on exported and re-imported object

Tags: uv, objects

I have a problem with an object texture
I import the object as obj and it's fine with the texture.

[image]

But when I export the object and import it again with another form or type
it's texture gets corrupt or change.

[image]

Since I am a beginner I do not know what to do.

Comment: Are you sure there is only [one UV map or multiple](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_management.html#uv-maps-panel)? If there are many probably object is exported with wrong one. Also please provide export settings, starting from file format and up to screenshot of the settings (you can add it in the comments). In general it's likely object is exported with another uv map (or it's edited with modifiers before exporting); export options tend to preserve at elast uv maps.

Comment: nope just 1 object with 1 uv map 
file format is srobj 
it's py goes like this
https://files.fm/u/psakhr58#/view/New+Text+Document.txt

Comment: I don't want to get too mystic but if you don't properly achieve one part of your work (uv's are bad), you can't reach the next step... go back to that for awhile and maybe in the meantime you'll find the root of the problem... just talking karma here I have no clue what's happening to your (bad ) uv's...

Answer (score 0):

try to choose **project from view** instead of unwrap .
[image]

Comment: That won't help with corrupted texture because will create another UV map; if image texture is already baked this solution is practically useless.

Comment: already tried project from view didn't help it's fine with obj exporting but im trying to export it with another type